# exchangelib: looking for winkerberos on an OS X system

Tags: python, exchange-server

I am attempting to install exchangelib on a Mac (OS X 10.13.5). I was having issues with the install, so I created a minimal environment in which to work:

---

```
pushd /tmp
curl -SLO https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash ./Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh -b -p /tmp/lxml
source /tmp/lxml/bin/activate
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 lxml -y
source activate py35
```

---

I then installed exchangelib within that environment. When I attempt to use it, though, I find that it's trying to load winkerberos instead of pykerberos.

---

```
>>> import exchangelib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py", line 2, in <module>
    import kerberos
ImportError: dlopen(/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kerberos.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mempcpy
  Referenced from: /tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kerberos.cpython-35m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kerberos.cpython-35m-darwin.so
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .account import Account
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/account.py", line 12, in <module>
    from exchangelib.services import GetUserOofSettings, SetUserOofSettings
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/services.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .transport import wrap, extra_headers, SOAPNS, TNS, MNS, ENS
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/exchangelib/transport.py", line 9, in <module>
    import requests_kerberos
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_kerberos/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .kerberos_ import HTTPKerberosAuth, REQUIRED, OPTIONAL, DISABLED
  File "/tmp/lxml/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py", line 4, in <module>
    import winkerberos as kerberos
ImportError: No module named 'winkerberos'
>>>
```

---

I'm kind of at a loss here. Any ideas how to get the install to not look for winkerberos?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying to load pykerberos first, which fails with a library issue (*Symbol not found: _mempcpy*) and as a fallback tries to load winkerberos, which it does not find. This should start working as soon as you can make the pykerberos on your system work.